# ¿Cómo ejecutar código PHP dentro de Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy intentando mostrar un `Select` que debe mostrar los `options` obtenidos desde una consulta a la base de datos, pero no los mustra y estoy casi seguro que hay algo errado en mí código `PHP` incluído dentro del `Jquery`

```
newRow: function () {
jQuery(".item-row:last").after('<td><select class="form-control" name="service_id[]" id="service_id"><option value="">Select</option><?php foreach($services as $service){if($selected_service->id!=$service->id){?><option value="1"><?php$service->description?></option><?php}endif}endforeach?></select></td>');

if (jQuery($.opt.delete).length > 0) {
    jQuery($.opt.delete).show();
}

return 1;
```

},

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Para interactuar desde el cliente (jQuery) con el servidor (PHP) generalmente se usa Ajax.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a buscar información al respecto. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es una muy mala forma de llenar un SELECT con php.

Crea un servicio web (en PHP) que regrese un JSON con los datos para los OPTIONS y con Query llenas el SELECT, es la opción más profesional y lógica.

Ejemplo: https://coderedirect.com/questions/1214/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php

Así estás separando la capa de presentación de la capa de negocio (Programación en capas)

Otra forma (funciona pero no muy profesional) es armar los OPTIONS desde PHP:

```
   <select id="sel_depart">
  <option value="0">- Select -</option>
  <?php 
  $sql_department = "SELECT * FROM department";
  $department_data = mysqli_query($con,$sql_department);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($department_data) ){
     $departid = $row['id'];
     $depart_name = $row['depart_name'];
  
     // Options
     echo "<option value='".$departid."' >".$depart_name."</option>";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Voy a crear otra pregunta más elaborada y con más detalles, la expuse así pensando que era problema de sintáxis.